# Can I run a script before a template file in yaml azure build pipeline script?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml script which runs a template.  I want to be able to run a script before it to start a service.  Is this possible?

```
stages:
- stage: BuildandDeploy
  variables:
  - group: nonprod
  jobs:
    - template: my/templates/shared.yml@templates
      parameters:
        # Version Config
        sourcebranch_name: '$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

I've tried to add a job before the template which doesn't seem to work.

```
stages:
- stage: BuildandDeploy
  variables:
  - group: nonprod
  jobs:
    - script: 'my.exe'
      displayName:  Start My Exe
    - template: my/templates/shared.yml@templates
      parameters:
        # Version Config
        sourcebranch_name: '$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your issue description, your template should contain an entire job. As shown below:

```
jobs:
- job: Ubuntu
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Hello Ubuntu"
  - bash: echo "Hello World"
```

When your template contains an entire job, it can only be replaced as a job. You can't add a task before a job.

If you want to run a task before running the template, you have two alternatives:

1.Rewrite your template so that it is a collection of tasks rather than a collection of tasks, as shown below. Accordingly, your pipeline YAML file may need to make some adjustments. This method preserves the integrity of your job, but may cause your template to lose its original meaning.

```
steps:
- bash: echo "Hello Ubuntu"
- bash: echo "Hello World"
```

2.Make the task you want to run in front of the template a separate job. This method retains the meaning of the template, but cuts apart your current job.